# Retrieving text from an element with children

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get the text "Weeeeee" but when i use `//td[@class='something']/text()` I got nothing

```
<td class="something">
    <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a> 
    Weeeeee
    <div>
        <a>something</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//td[@class='something']/text()[normalize-space() != ''][1]
```

as there are *three* text nodes in your example, the first and the last one consist of whitespace only.

Highlighted with square brackets:

```
<td class="something">[\n
----]<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>[\n
----Weeeeee\n
----]<div>
      <a>something</a>
   </div>[\n
]</td>
```